# How do I get the "Terminal Services Profile Path"/CtxWFProfilePath from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, user-profile, terminal-services

I am trying to get the profile path from the `Remote Desktop Services Profile` tab in AD.
I picked a few users to test with and each user has a path in that tab. (picture below)

Each time I try and get this field through PowerShell I am disappointed to get nothing.

Does anyone know what could be preventing me from getting the info I so desire?

Thank you

### With Quest:

```
Get-QADuser $user | select TsProfilePath
```

This returns an empty string

### With ADSI:

```
$user = "JBiggs"
$ADUser = Get-qADUser $user | select -ExpandProperty DN
$ADUser = [ADSI]”LDAP://$ADUser”
$ADUser.psbase.InvokeGet(“terminalservicesprofilepath”)
```

This errors out

```
Exception calling "InvokeGet" with "1" argument(s): "Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"
At line:4 char:25
+ $ADUser.psbase.InvokeGet <<<< (“terminalservicesprofilepath”)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

[image: Picture with the field]

## Found what I need but cannot decode

As it turns out the old way of storing this information is through the `UserParameters` value.  It is stored as a base64 blob.  The old way remains in use as you upgrade through newer versions of windows server, so mine has been around for a long time.  When this happens the new fields remain blank which is what I am seeing with some of my examples above.

```
$id = "JXD122"
$User = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(Get-qADUser $id | select -ExpandProperty Path)
$w.userParameters
```

So I am able to see sort of what I need in this.  Within it is the text `CtxWFProfilePath` followed by what appear to be Chinese symbols.  So now my last step is to decode what I am seeing.  Anyone know how?

Comment: that's what I am doing with the ADSI example above, gives me that error above.  I am not attached to using quest, just wanted to try multiple options before posting here.

Comment: It is a distinguished name, however I don't have access to the get-aduser command as its being run on a client system not on the DC itself

Comment: crap you are right paul... how did I miss that. one minute, let me fix that

Comment: okay so it turns out I just copied the wrong example for the LDAP.  Please see the changes I made to show where the LDAP query is coming from, should be run-able for testing

Comment: what version of Windows Server is running on your DC

Comment: if you are running 2k8 or above try `$ADUser.psbase.InvokeGet(“msTSProfilePath”)`

Comment: it is 2k8, and that line almost worked, no error but it returns a blank string

Comment: hmm i just tested both attributes on a system at a clients site and i also get an empty line with msTSProfilepath but i get the correct output with terminalservicesprofilepath, are you sure the user you are querying has a profile path entry? i get the same error as you if i query a user that doesnt have one

Comment: I am 100% sure the user has one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out Legacy DCs that have been upgraded *keep* storing this information in the `UserParameters` object.  And this object is stupidly encoded for some reason.

It took me some time but I was able to decode it using the following website as reference: http://daduke.org/linux/userparameters.html

Here is my quick and dirty PowerShell function to return the *TS Profile Path*. Works every time for me.

**Note: Requires Quest.** This script uses the `get-qADUser` command. For this you need to install the [*Quest ActiveDirectory cmdlets*](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Quest_ActiveRoles_Management_Shell_Download).

```
function get-TSPP($id) {
    $enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
    $User = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(Get-qADUser $id | select -ExpandProperty Path)
    $coded = $user.userParameters.tostring().split("")[-1].replace("〰","").replace("CtxWFProfilePath","").ToCharArray()
    $result = @()
    foreach ($c in $coded) {
        $bytes = $enc.GetBytes($c)
        $d = @()
        foreach ($byte in $bytes) {
            $d += [Convert]::ToString($byte, 2) 
        }
        $d = -join $d
        $control_Y = -join $d[4..9]
        $yyyy = -join $d[10..13]
        $control_X = -join $d[14..19]
        $xxxx = -join $d[20..23]

        if ($control_X -eq "011010") {
            $xxxx = [Convert]::ToString([Convert]::ToInt32($xxxx,2) + 9,2)
        }
        if ($control_Y -eq "011010") {
            $yyyy = [Convert]::ToString([Convert]::ToInt32($yyyy,2) + 9,2)
        }

        $binary = @($xxxx, $yyyy)

        $result += [char][Convert]::ToInt32((-join $binary), 2) 
    }

    return -join $result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to make an export to c:\temp\tspath.csv

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq "true"}  | ForEach-Object {
   $User = [ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)"  
   $User.psbase.InvokeGet(“terminalservicesprofilepath”)  
   } |Out-File C:\temp\tspath.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ADSI example, `OU=Users,OU=123,OU=place,OU=state,DC=dc1,DC=NET` is an OU, whose underlying ADSI object does not implement the IADsTSUserEx interface.

If you pass the DN of a user, it should work.

Comment: I messed up the example, I have since removed that and included it directly from the user object

Comment: I had no knowledge on Quest cmdlet. Can you take a look at the value of $ADUser right after `$ADUser = Get-qADUser $user | select -ExpandProperty DN`? Is the value really a DN of a user? By the error, it's the same issue  (IADsTSUserEx interface is not implemented).

Comment: CN=user1,OU=Users,OU=site,OU=city,OU=state,DC=,DC=company,DC=NET   .. looks correct to me